# docker import loses the image's name, repository, and tag

Tags: docker, container, podman

When I export an image with

```
podman save --format oci-archive -o /tmp/image-oci.tar localhost/foobar-centos-7:92
```

Or,

```
podman save --format docker-archive -o /tmp/image-docker.tar localhost/foobar-centos-7:92
```

I can import those images, with `docker import`, but they do not have the `REPOSITORY` or `TAG`

```
REPOSITORY                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                        <none>              93a9f3ac67ef        15 seconds ago      1.23GB
```

Is there a way to preserve this information? I don't see an option on `docker import` or `podman save`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Using `docker load`

The command `docker load` can do this with docker-archive images,

```
podman save --format docker-archive -o /tmp/image-docker.tar localhost/foobar-centos-7:92
docker load -i /tmp/image-docker.tar
```

## Using `docker import`

The last argument to `docker import` specifies that,

```
Usage:  docker import [OPTIONS] file|URL|- [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Just wrap it like this,

```
img=localhost/foobar-centos-7:92
podman save --format oci-archive -o /tmp/image-oci.tar "$img"
docker import /tmp/image-oci.tar "$img"
```